# Create link to class from macro documentation in Doxygen

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

I have a macro which affects certain classes and want to document it with Doxygen. Example is:

> foo.h

```
#include <ns/config.h>
namespace ns{
  /// @brief Represents a Foo
  class Foo {...};

  /// @brief Takes a Foo and bars it
  void bar(Foo);
}
```

> config.h

```
/// @file

/// Changes Foo to do Baz in <foo.h>
#define Bazify_Foo 1
```

I get correct documentation for all classes, functions and macros (the `/// @file` was key to get the macro doc) and links to `Foo` from the `bar` docu, as well as links to `foo.h` in the macro docu. However it does not link `Foo` in the macro docu and using `/ref Foo` results in warning (explicit link request ... could not be resolved)

Is this supported by DoxyGen? How?

Comment: did you try `ns::Foo`?

Comment: (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻ Yep, that works... Any idea how to shorten that though? The whole library consists of only 1 (nested) namespace so that is rather distracting

Comment: I hope you already went through the discussion, so I will keep my comment short: Dont use a macro here.

Comment: Sure. In this case it is a switch macro: Either use from namespace A or namespace B for good reasons (TM)

Comment: maybe defining an ALIAS like `Foo=\ref ns::Foo "Foo"`  But you still wil have the distracting `\Foo` or `@Foo` in your comment.